# What, exactly, does a C toolchain expect to be linked with for bare-metal development?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, embedded

I've done a good bit of embedded C development, but always from inside vendors' walled gardens. As this is an unequivocally horrendous experience, for my most recent project I set out to get GCC, OpenOCD, GDB, and Emacs to play nice in my usual Linux environment. I had test projects set up and working well, but I'm running up against a linker error I'm unable to chase out, and I'm wondering, beyond the error specifically, about **debugging methodology** for this class of thing.

My actual problem: I have a TI tm4c123, via their "launchpad" dev board. I'm compiling from 32-bit Arch. I yoinked someone's [example project guide](https://www.shawndsilva.com/blog/embedded%20systems/makefiles-for-embedded-systems), mainly for license reasons, and altered the Makefile for my project. No problems; it's all compiling, flashing, and debugging perfectly fine. Until I need to `malloc`. Then, something about an "undefined reference to _sbrk:" from looking at myriad other questions, this appears to be related to not linking in libraries that provide shim definitions of syscalls used by the `libc`. Fine. Looking through the toolchain's library search path, I find `libnosys.a`, but linking with that seems to only push the problem down a step, and yields an "undefined reference to end." At this point, I'm concerned about a bug in the *linker script* I'm using, or some other similarly low-level issue.

While I'd welcome a quick resolution to my particular problem ("add option `foo` to compile step `bar`" or something), I'd actually prefer if, in addition, anyone could point me to resources that would help me understand how MCUs, embedded ABIs, linkers, and libraries all interact―what, exactly, are the assumptions that the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain is making about the execution environment and the code that'll eventually get linked in? How does one modify or satisfy those assumptions, in order to actually get an `.elf` that flashes and runs correctly on an MCU? There seem to be a great many questions related to similarly-named errors, and they range over a large variety of actual underlying bugs. Understanding *exactly* what the tools are doing and why would help greatly in sorting out the differences.

Here's a minimum non-working example, for discussion:

```c
// ./main.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint8_t *ptr = malloc(3);
  ptr[0] = 0xb0;
  ptr[1] = 0x0b;
  
}
```

```
# ./Makefile
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld


CFLAGS = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -ffunction-sections \
    -fdata-sections -MD  -std=c2x -Wall -Wextra -Werror -DPART_${MCU} -c -O0 -Dgcc -ggdb


LIBGCC := ${shell ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -print-libgcc-file-name}
LIBC := ${shell ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -print-file-name=libc.a}
LIBM := ${shell ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -print-file-name=libm.a}
LIBSTUB := ${shell ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -print-file-name=libnosys.a}
LDFLAGS = -T linkerscript.ld -e Reset_Handler --gc-sections  '${LIBM}'  '${LIBGCC}' '${LIBC}' '${LIBSTUB}'



all: mwe.elf

startup.o: startup.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

mwe.elf: main.o startup.o
    $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)


.PHONY: all
```

Include also the [./startup.h](https://github.com/shawn-dsilva/tm4c-linux-template/blob/master/inc/startup.h), [./startup.c](https://github.com/shawn-dsilva/tm4c-linux-template/blob/master/libs/startup.c), and [./linkerscript.ld](https://github.com/shawn-dsilva/tm4c-linux-template/blob/master/ld/TM4C123GH6PM.ld) files from the project guide linked above; I omitted them for brevity. Putting all mentioned files in a single directory and running `make` (with an ARM gcc toolchain installed: `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, `arm-none-eabi-newlib`, and `arm-none-eabi-binutils` for me on Arch) has reproduced the exact error, along with some extra warnings.

Comment: Even though you aren't using newlib, it's a good resource for the dependencies of the various C library routine. See https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#malloc

Comment: @stark I believe I _am_ using newlib...

Comment: Then you should definitely read [the newlib documentation](https://sourceware.org/newlib/).  Start with the FAQ, the README, and the first couple of sections of the C library docs.  Next, you should probably follow the instructions in the README for building and running the test suite.  That will confirm that your build actually works, and get you better acclimated to newlib use.

Comment: "Until I need to malloc" One of the root problems is that this is senseless to begin with - it's a Cortex M4 not a PC. Please check out [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121).

Comment: You might also want to compile with `-ffreestanding` to tell the compiler that it isn't dealing with a PC. This will enable a sensible format of main() and prevent inlined standard library calls in the machine code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin with a preamble: embedded systems are generally designed to be small and target-specific. The typical embedded application *doesn't need* the full power of the GNU C Library and it *doesn't want* it either since memory size really matters in embedded systems. Therefore, specialized C standard libraries, such as [`newlib`](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) or `redlib` by NXP, have been designed to carefully meet the requirements of these applications.

For a brief but detailed explanation of the general compilation and linking process you can refer to this [link](https://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html). This process clearly applies to microprocessors as well as MCU like Cortex-M4. Compilers like `arm-none-eabi` include in their release the `newlib` library compiled with a specific configuration (see [this](https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/compilers-and-libraries-forum/53310/gcc-arm-none-eabi-what-were-the-newlib-compilation-options) and [this](https://sourceware.org/newlib/README) to understand what it means) and this library can be linked to your application (`libc.a` in your makefile) or can be totally ignored with the `nostdlib` compilation option for applications that don't need it and/or want to implement the functions by themselves and/or want to use another standard library implementation.

`newlib` offers the implementations of the C standard library functions, such as `memcpy` and `strcat`, as well as system calls such as `open`, `read` and `write`. Some of these functions (including `malloc`) rely on subroutines typically provided by the OS as explained [here](https://www.sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls). If the embedded application runs with an OS, then these subroutines should be implemented and the `newlib` library should not have any problems at all. However, if the embedded application runs on a *bare* system without an OS support, then you have two possibilities:

- Link to the *stubs* provided by `newlib` (`libnosys.a` in your makefile) which are a minimal implementation to let the syscall runs or fails gracefully.
- Implement your own subroutines according to your needs.

Finally, the reason why you can't link your application is the missing reference to the symbol `end` which is used by the *stub* version of the function `sbrk` used by `malloc`. Let's consider the implementation of this function from the `newlib` official GIT [sources](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git):

```
/* Version of sbrk for no operating system.  */

#include "config.h"
#include <_syslist.h>

void *
_sbrk (incr)
     int incr;
{
   extern char   end; /* Set by linker.  */
   static char * heap_end;
   char *        prev_heap_end;

   if (heap_end == 0)
     heap_end = & end;

   prev_heap_end = heap_end;
   heap_end += incr;

   return (void *) prev_heap_end;
}
```

Essentially, this function updates the current heap end by the memory size requested and returns the previous value. At beginning, the heap end points to the address of the symbol `end` which, as pointed out by the code itself, must be defined by the linker through the linker script.

A possible way to put the `end` symbol in the linker script could be:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 256K /* FLASH size 256KB */
    RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 32K/* RAM size 32KB */
}

SECTIONS
{
    PROVIDE( _stack_ptr = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM));

    /* .text, .data, .bss, .rodata */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    end = . ;   /* Heap start */
}
```

In this way the stack starts at end of RAM and grows downward (towards lower addresses), while the heap starts at `end`, after the data sections, and grows upward (towards higher addresses).